# How can I crash/kill a running app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, adb

I would like to **crash** my Android app by using command-line ADB tool during my app is running, is it possible to do? and how ?

(Basically, I want to test if my app persist the necessary informations when it is crashed. So, I would like to demo this by crash my app by some command-line tool, like ADB.)

******* Update ****************

In other words, how to kill my app process by using ADB tool?

Comment: Why downvote my post???? What is wrong with my question:(

Comment: I don't agree with you JoxTraex. Basically what I am asking is how to kill my app process by using ADB tool. I don't see any problem of asking for this.

Comment: I am sure there will be another Android newbie who will be also interested and ask it. Downvote is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can easily kill my app from Eclipse DDMS. Just stop the process , e.g. stop  "com.my.app"

Comment: It's the only way to test restoration when system kills the app during memory pressure. For Android Studio it's important to launch it through menu Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 8):

kill probably won't work.

```
adb shell am force-stop <your.app.package>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually trigger a crash via the "crash" param to `adb shell am`

```
adb shell am crash <package name>
```

This is an obscure option but can be confirmed when emulator is running via: `adb shell am help`

Details: [reference](https://gist.github.com/meramsey/b9c98032a34612a1a29f9fd2059156a5#file-gistfile1-txt-L125-L126)

```
crash [--user <USER_ID>] <PACKAGE|PID>
      Induce a VM crash in the specified package or process
```

Wish this was easier to find I cannot find the original source where I found it but should be more obviously listed on docs page vs only shown when connected am help menu...
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am

Answer (score 3):

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

Try the below command in abd shell.

Comment: Hi, I got error "/system/bin/sh: kill: 3511: Operation not permitted"

Comment: `adb shell run-as <package name> kill <PID>` works even without rooting

Answer (score 2):

You can kill your app from the shell:

```
adb -s YOURDEVICEID shell
top // find your app pid
kill -p YOUR_APP_PID
```

Comment: But I got -p unkonwn option, I removed -p and then got "Operation not permitted", I then change to use sudo kill 3511, I got the same error. WHy?

Comment: I think you should use @bas answer once you know the pid.

Answer (score 0):

App crashing at runtime is nothing but an **Occurance of Exception**, The place after which you want to crash your app, write a logic which causes for an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to crash your app is to add an Exception to your package.
Like division by 0 - add it to your app code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've got the answer yet. The answer is pretty much the same as @bas but instead of using , you need to you the package name

```
adb shell am force-stop <package name>
```

you can get the package name by using this command

```
adb shell pm list package -3
```

-3 means all 3rd party apps that are installed in device.